# Toggle between two hidden forms wrapped in <div> elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hoping to find some help!

I've created an HTML Drop down select menu with two options: two different forms that I've included in my HTML wrapped in  elements that are not displayed using CSS.
I've coded Javascript to try and toggle between the two forms upon clicking the appropriate option on the menu and then clicking go. However, I cannot figure it out. Here is a snippet of my code.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("userForm");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<form> 
 <div class="dropDown">
   <select id="select" onclick="myFunction()">
      <option disabled selected>Choose to fill out help form or general feedback form please.</option>
      <option id="user">User Feedback Form</option>
      <option id="help">User Help Form</option> 
      <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="go()">
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="userForm">A</div>
<div id="helpForm">B</div>
```

After this script, I go on to include both forms individually wrapped in  elements with unique ID's. Please help!

I've tried the original Javascript I wrote above. Only one form will show up. I've also tried to code an If, else, and elif but I am new to Javascript. My Professor told me to search online for answers which seems wrong but I've been experimenting for hours with no success.

Comment: After my script, here is the rest of my code...two forms wrapped in <div> elements

Comment: <div id="userForm"> </div> <div id="helpForm"></div> Sorry it won't let me post the entire HTML included in the <div> elements

Comment: You may want to listen for the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) and use the [`HTMLSelectElement.value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#htmlselectelement.value) to decide which form to show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems on this snippet you are just toggling the `userForm` to be seen or not, but you are not doing anything with the help one.
Other than that there are other things that are wrong, you are toggling theyr visibility checking if `userForm` has `display: none` or not, but this should be done based on what option is selected.
The javascript code for this should be:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("userForm");
    var y = document.getElementById("helpForm");
    if (selected option is "user") { //You can easily figure out how to properly write it
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display = "none";
    } else if (selected option is "help") {  //This one too
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Another way to improve it is by using classes to hide/show elements instead of `x.style.display` but for now it is just fine! :)

Let me know if this was of any help

Comment: <script>
  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("userForm");
  var y = document.getElementById("helpForm");
  if (x.style.display == "user") { //You can easily figure out how to properly write it
   x.style.display = "block";
   y.style.display = "none";
  } else if (y.style.display == "help") {  //This one too
   x.style.display = "none";
   y.style.display = "block";
  }
 }
 </script>

Comment: Nope, you have to check what option of the select has been selected, it's not safe to check on what kind of "display" a single box has.